# Como criar uma grid de input em asp.net C# - MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Basicamente tenho um formulário e estou abrindo uma janela(modal) com uma lista de funcionários e por javascript consigo adicionar o e-mail dos mesmo no formulário que será salvo, em outra linguagem nesse caso eu iria solucionar criando o input dos emails assim:

```
< input name="email[ ]" />
```

Na Controller eu iria pegar essa tag `email[]` com todos os e-mail adicionados, já em asp.net não sei qual seria o melhor jeito de fazer uma tela assim, tentei fazer igual mas na controller o parametro(formColletion) do Post não chega como um array de e-mail, ele entende apenas como um único campo. 
Obs.: Queria solucionar sem AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é o jeito errado de resolver. No ASP.NET MVC, você deve passar ao formulário ou uma coleção de *Models* ou uma coleção de *ViewModels*. Pro exemplo de *ViewModel*, você deve declarar uma classe da seguinte forma:

```
public class FuncionarioViewModel 
{
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public String Email { get; set; }
}
```

Ao montar seu formulário, você deve usar [o pacote NuGet BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). Ele prepara seu formulário para preencher corretamente o objeto que irá para o *Controller*. Isto pode ser feito declarando uma classe mestre para o formulário e usando o *ViewModel* já definido para os detalhes:

```
public class MeuFormularioViewModel
{
    ...
    public ICollection<FuncionarioViewModel> Funcionarios { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Sua *Action* no *Controller* ficará assim:

```
public ActionResult Salvar(MeuFormularioViewModel viewModel) 
{
    // Coloque sua lógica para salvar os registros aqui
}
```

[Respondi várias perguntas muito parecidas, que você pode conferir aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem). Recomendo a leitura para pormenores de como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, uma forma simples de fazer isso, na sua view você poem varios inputs com o mesmo name.

```
<input name="email" value="teste@email.com" />
<input name="email" value="teste1@email.com" />
<input name="email" value="teste1@email.com" />
<input name="email" value="teste1@email.com" />
```

Ai no seu controller basta ter isso:

```
public ActionResult NomeController(strin[] email)
```

Que ele vai recuperar perfeitamente